# SSE memory access

Tags: c, sse, simd, gaussian

I need to perform Gaussian Elimination using SSE and I am not sure how to access each element(32 bits) from the 128 bit registers(each storing 4 elements). This is the original code(without using SSE):

```
unsigned int i, j, k;

for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i ++)             /* Copy the contents of the A matrix into the U matrix. */
    for(j = 0; j < num_elements; j++)
        U[num_elements * i + j] = A[num_elements*i + j];


for (k = 0; k < num_elements; k++){             /* Perform Gaussian elimination in place on the U matrix. */
    for (j = (k + 1); j < num_elements; j++){   /* Reduce the current row. */

        if (U[num_elements*k + k] == 0){
            printf("Numerical instability detected. The principal diagonal element is zero. \n");
            return 0;
        }

        /* Division step. */
        U[num_elements * k + j] = (float)(U[num_elements * k + j] / U[num_elements * k + k]);
    }

    U[num_elements * k + k] = 1;             /* Set the principal diagonal entry in U to be 1. */

    for (i = (k+1); i < num_elements; i++){
        for (j = (k+1); j < num_elements; j++)
            /* Elimnation step. */
            U[num_elements * i + j] = U[num_elements * i + j] -\
                                      (U[num_elements * i + k] * U[num_elements * k + j]);

        U[num_elements * i + k] = 0; 
    } 
}
```

Okay I'm getting segmentation fault[core dumped] with this code. I'm new to SSE. Can someone help? Thanks.

```
 int i,j,k;
 __m128 a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i;

for (i = 0; i < num_rows; i++)
{
for (j = 0; j < num_rows; j += 4)
{
    int index = num_rows * i + j;
   __m128 v = _mm_loadu_ps(&A[index]); // load 4 x floats
   _mm_storeu_ps(&U[index], v);         // store 4 x floats

}
}
for (k = 0; k < num_rows; k++){  

 a_i= _mm_load_ss(&U[num_rows*k+k]);         


    for (j = (4*k + 1); j < num_rows; j+=4){
               b_i= _mm_loadu_ps(&U[num_rows*k+j]);// Reduce the currentrow. 

    if (U[num_rows*k+k] == 0){
    printf("Numerical instability detected.);

        }

        /* Division step. */
        b_i =    _mm_div_ps(b_i, a_i);
  }

    a_i = _mm_set_ss(1);           

    for (i = (k+1); i < num_rows; i++){
  d_i= _mm_load_ss(&U[num_rows*i+k]);
        for (j = (4*k+1); j < num_rows; j+=4){
           c_i= _mm_loadu_ps(&U[num_rows*i+j]); /* Elimnation step. */
        b_i= _mm_loadu_ps(&U[num_rows*k+j]);    
            c_i = _mm_sub_ps(c_i, _mm_mul_ss(b_i,d_i));
        }
       d_i= _mm_set_ss(0); 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Lots of fundamental mistakes in your initial attempt - maybe try something simpler first, in order to learn the basics of SIMD coding?

Comment: The x86 tag wiki (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) has links.  If you find a good intro/overview/getting-started guide, please edit the link into the wiki, or leave a comment here and I'll check it out.  Most of the links are to reference material that's useful when you know the basics, but have to look up which instruction does exactly what, and what's available.

Comment: Yeah I see the mistake. Thanks for the links.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. Yes the matrices are square of size num_elements. I am supposed to use it as a flattened 2D array and like Paul said, the objective is to learn SIMD. Thanks. I'll try to build on that

Comment: So I will have to use the 128 bit register just as a temporary variable while copying data instead of using them to store the matrices themselves?

Comment: Try not to fixate on the XMM registers themselves - just think in terms of `__m128i` *variables*. This works much the same as with e.g. `int` variables and general purpose registers - the compiler takes care of which variables reside in registers at any given time - this relieves you, the programmer, from the task of thinking about low-level house-keeping details.

Comment: @PeterCordes, the links and description for the x86 tag is awesome! That's a great resource.

Comment: @PaulR I've updated the code. Something is causing a segmentation fault. I commented out each line in the function to find out which line is causing the error but came up with nothing. None of the printf() statements I tried giving printed anything.

Comment: Change all your `_mm_load_ps` intrinsics to `_mm_loadu_ps` .

Comment: @PaulR I tried doing that. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Rather than keep editing fixes into the question, it would probably be better at this point to post a new question, with the latest version of your *actual code* (the above code doesn't even compile), preferably as a [mcve], and explain what the remaining problems are (i.e. expected output versus actual output).

Answer (score 2):

In order to get you started, your first loop should be more like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < num_elements; j += 4)
    {
        int index = num_elements * i + j;
        __m128i v = _mm_loadu_ps((__m128i *)&A[index]); // load 4 x floats
        _mm_storeu_ps((__m128i *)&U[index], v);         // store 4 x floats
    }
}
```

This assumes that `num_elements` is a multiple of 4, and that neither `A` nor `U` is correctly aligned.

Comment: If he store the matrix in a single array, why the nested loop?

Comment: @Bob__: well why not ? ;-) It's probably a "flattened" 2D array, and of course he could just as well use `memcpy` in this instance, but since the objective is to learn SIMD coding for matrices it makes more sense to use two nested loops for this example.

Comment: That's ok, but his original code is wrong too. Check the boundaries of the loop. Shouldn't be something like `for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i ++)          U[i] = A[i];`

Comment: @Bob__: I'm guessing the matrices are square, of size `num_elements` x `num_elements` (except they are flattened) - if the OP can clarify (and fix their scalar code if necessary) then I'll update my answer accordingly.