# Implementing Gaussian Elimination using SSE

Tags: c, x86, linear-algebra, sse, simd

I'm trying to implement Gaussian elimination using SSE, but I think my alignment may be off, or I may be executing some blocks in the wrong order.

As an example, here's the first 8x8 submatrix of the input matrix, a matrix computed using a serial implementation, and the incorrect output matrix:

input matrix:

```
50.000000 15.000000 44.000000 18.000000 15.000000 21.000000 32.000000 6.000000 
35.000000 39.000000 26.000000 44.000000 8.000000 7.000000 24.000000 11.000000 
36.000000 21.000000 45.000000 15.000000 17.000000 31.000000 48.000000 9.000000 
33.000000 15.000000 13.000000 41.000000 29.000000 41.000000 22.000000 30.000000 
46.000000 19.000000 35.000000 37.000000 32.000000 17.000000 29.000000 43.000000 
42.000000 11.000000 23.000000 31.000000 31.000000 6.000000 42.000000 22.000000 
40.000000 34.000000 21.000000 8.000000 14.000000 7.000000 47.000000 14.000000 
7.000000 27.000000 33.000000 17.000000 4.000000 37.000000 11.000000 43.000000
```

reference matrix:

```
1.000000 0.300000 0.880000 0.360000 0.300000 0.420000 0.640000 0.120000 
0.000000 1.000000 -0.168421 1.101754 -0.087719 -0.270175 0.056140 0.238596 
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 -0.611648 0.471791 1.239255 1.621728 0.149377 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 1.878897 3.329519 1.773631 1.905714 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 22.894316 9.444982 -9.377328 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 0.259213 -0.374202 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 -0.914501 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
```

incorrect output matrix:

```
1.000000 0.300000 0.880000 0.360000 0.300000 0.420000 0.640000 0.120000 
0.000000 1.000000 -0.168421 1.101754 -0.087719 -0.270175 0.056140 0.238596 
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 -0.611648 0.471791 1.239255 1.621728 0.149377 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 1.878897 3.329519 1.773631 1.905714 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -1.520596 -34.812996 -14.361997 14.259123 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 260.456787 139.866196 -114.162613 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -399578.125000 326107.625000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -35436253184.000000
```

And here's the function itself:

```
void 
gauss_eliminate_using_sse(const Matrix A, Matrix U)
{
    // iterators
    unsigned int i, j, k;
    // shorthand for matrix elements
    float *a_el = A.elements;
    float *u_el = U.elements;

    // load A matrix into U matrix
    for (i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < MATRIX_SIZE/4; ++j){
            // copy four elements at a time
            __m128 buffer = _mm_load_ps(&a_el[MATRIX_SIZE*i + j*4]);
            _mm_store_ps(&u_el[MATRIX_SIZE*i + j*4], buffer); 
        }
    }

    // for each pivot in the matrix
    for (k = 0; k < MATRIX_SIZE; ++k){
        // find the pivot at U[k][k]
        float pivot = u_el[MATRIX_SIZE*k + k];
        // ensure matrix stability
        if (pivot == 0)
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        // load pivot into all four sections of register
        __m128 m_pivot = _mm_set1_ps(pivot);
        __m128 buffer;

        // Division step
        // Beginning with the block containing u[k][k], divide each four-word block by the pivot
        for (j = k/4*4; j < MATRIX_SIZE/4; ++j){
            buffer = _mm_load_ps(&u_el[MATRIX_SIZE*k + j*4]);
            buffer = _mm_div_ps(buffer, m_pivot);
            _mm_store_ps(&u_el[MATRIX_SIZE*k + j*4], buffer);
        }

        // Elimination step
        // Iterating over each row
        for (i = (k+1); i < MATRIX_SIZE; ++i){
            // If in one of the last four blocks, a four-word block cannot be created. Process serially.
            if (i > MATRIX_SIZE - 4) {
                for (j = (k+1); j < MATRIX_SIZE; ++j)
                    u_el[MATRIX_SIZE * i + j] = u_el[MATRIX_SIZE * i + j] - (u_el[MATRIX_SIZE * i + k] * u_el[MATRIX_SIZE * k + j]);
            } else {
                // If u[i][k+1] is not aligned on a four-word block, process serially until reaching an index that is
                int serial_process_count = ((k+1) % 4 == 0) ? 0 : 4 - ((k+1)%4);
                for (j = (k+1); j < (k+1+serial_process_count); ++j)
                    u_el[MATRIX_SIZE * i + j] = u_el[MATRIX_SIZE * i + j] - (u_el[MATRIX_SIZE * i + k] * u_el[MATRIX_SIZE * k + j]);

                // Iterate over each four-word block, beginning at the index reached by lines 158-161
                __m128 m0, m1, m2, m3, m4;
                // fetch U[MATRIX_SIZE * i + k], placing the same word in each index
                m1 = _mm_load1_ps(&u_el[MATRIX_SIZE * i + k]);
                for (j = (k+1+serial_process_count); j < MATRIX_SIZE; j+=4){
                    // fetch U[MATRIX_SIZE * i + j + n], where n = 0..3
                    m0 = _mm_load_ps(&u_el[MATRIX_SIZE * i + j]);
                    // fetch U[MATRIX_SIZE * k + j + n], where n = 0..3
                    m2 = _mm_load_ps(&u_el[MATRIX_SIZE * k + j]);

                    // U[MATRIX_SIZE * i + k] * U[MATRIX_SIZE * k + j]
                    m3 = _mm_mul_ps(m1, m2);
                    // U[MATRIX_SIZE * i - j] - m1
                    m4 = _mm_sub_ps(m0, m3);
                    // U[MATRIX_SIZE * i - j] = m0
                    _mm_store_ps(&u_el[MATRIX_SIZE * i + j], m4);
                }
             }
             u_el[MATRIX_SIZE * i + k] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help debugging would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you a class-mate of [@amateur_coder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33397972/sse-memory-access) ?

Comment: I'm a bit suspicious about `j = k/4*4` in the last loop

Comment: You were right to be suspicious about j = k/4*4. I was using it to make sure that I started at an index divisible by four, but I should have processed some elements individually until reaching such an index.

Comment: @PaulR, I probably am, but I wouldn't know them personally. There are 40-50 people in the class.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the issue by fixing the loop bounds. At first, I had tried to start each loop at an index divisible by four by like this:

```
j = k/4*4
```

And had assumed I could reprocess elements. I should have done something like this:

```
// Division Step
// Determine the number of elements that must be processed serially
// so that the remainder can be processed in groups of 4
int serial_process_count = (MATRIX_SIZE-(k+1)) % 4;

// for each element found, divide by the pivot serially
if (serial_process_count >= 1)
    u_el[MATRIX_SIZE*k + k + 1] = u_el[MATRIX_SIZE*k + k + 1]/pivot;
if (serial_process_count >= 2)
    u_el[MATRIX_SIZE*k + k + 2] = u_el[MATRIX_SIZE*k + k + 2]/pivot;
if (serial_process_count >= 3)
    u_el[MATRIX_SIZE*k + k + 3] = u_el[MATRIX_SIZE*k + k + 3]/pivot;

// for the remaining elements, divide by the pivot in groups of four
for (j = (k+1+serial_process_count); j < MATRIX_SIZE; j+=4){
    buffer = _mm_load_ps(&u_el[MATRIX_SIZE*k + j]);
    buffer = _mm_div_ps(buffer, m_pivot);
    _mm_store_ps(&u_el[MATRIX_SIZE*k + j], buffer);
}
```

for both the division and elimination steps.